# Anchor Link Tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

To track the anchor link clicks as pageviews in universal analytics i used the following code on my single page website.

```
        var hashtag = /#\S+/

        jQuery('.navbar li a').click(function(){
            var match = jQuery(this).attr('href').match(hashtag);
            ga('send', 'pageview', '/' + match[0]);
        })
        /*
```

Now i changed to googel tag manager. Universal analytics is still working but the anchor links are not tracked.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be or how i can track the anchor link pageviews with google tag manager?

Comment: Have you tried to include your code as a custom HTML tag that fires on all page (all one page, I guess in your case)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a macro (variable) to form URL (get link text) for virtual pageview and Universal Analytics tag with this macro in More setting - Basic configuration - Document path.

In new GTM you should use More settings - Fields to Set - Field Name= page, Value={{your variable}}.

The firing rule for this tag will be click on link on your page.

Comment: I'm unable to find More setting -> Basic Configuration -> Document path when creating my tag. Could this be because I'm using the new google tag manager interface?

Comment: In new GTM you can use More settings - Fields to Set - Field Name= page, Value={{your variable}}

Comment: you rule mrbubu :) please consider adding this to your original answer